# Adding Maps to WPF applications

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, maps, kml

I have a WPF application that graphically represents a car trajectory between cities.

Till now, it's just circles and line between them on a white background.

Is there a way to add some functionality like Google Maps does, say, link circles to physical coordinates and instead of lines draw real paths following the roads?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course its possible but you have to get access to detailed route information. 
First question of course is if the routes should be displayed as ideal (calculated) routes or as actually completed routes.
One Possibility is to include a webbrowser and use the Google Maps API in Javascript or otherwise [great maps](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) which is a .NET map library.

Answer (score 0):

For the rendering part of the problem, you can probably use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx#paths) class to define a collection of line segments/bezier curves.

Comment: I already use the Path class in my drawing... but this is not linked with the maps...